# I'm trying to retrieve all http and https links from a websites but sometimes im getting null exception

Tags: c#, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
   int y = 0;
   string url = @"http://www.google.co.il";
   string urls = @"http://www.bing.com/images/search?q=cat&go=&form=QB&qs=n";

   public Form1()
   {
       InitializeComponent();
       //webCrawler(urls, 3);
       List<string> a = webCrawler(urls, 1);
       //GetAllImages();
   }

   private int factorial(int n)
   {
      if (n == 0) return 1;
      else y = n * factorial(n - 1);
      listBox1.Items.Add(y);
      return y;
   }

   private List<string> getLinks(HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument document)
   {
       List<string> mainLinks = new List<string>();

       if (document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]") == null)
       { }

       foreach (HtmlNode link in document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]"))
       {
           var href = link.Attributes["href"].Value;
           mainLinks.Add(href);
       }

       return mainLinks;
   }

   private List<string> webCrawler(string url, int levels)
   {
      HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc;
      HtmlWeb hw = new HtmlWeb(); 

      List<string> webSites;// = new List<string>();
      List<string> csFiles = new List<string>();

      csFiles.Add("temp string to know that something is happening in level = " + levels.ToString());
      csFiles.Add("current site name in this level is : "+url);
      /* later should be replaced with real cs files .. cs files links..*/

      doc = hw.Load(url);
      webSites = getLinks(doc);

      if (levels == 0)
      {
         return csFiles;
      }
      else
      {
         int actual_sites = 0;

         for (int i = 0; i < webSites.Count() && i< 100000; i++) // limiting ourseleves for 20 sites for each level for now..
         //or it will take forever.
         {
             string t = webSites[i];
             /*
                    if (!webSites.Contains(t))
                    {
                        webCrawler(t, levels - 1);
                    }
             */

             if ( (t.StartsWith("http://")==true) || (t.StartsWith("https://")==true) ) // replace this with future FilterJunkLinks function
             {
                actual_sites++;
                csFiles.AddRange(webCrawler(t, levels - 1));
                richTextBox1.Text += t + Environment.NewLine;
             }
          }

          // report to a message box only at high levels..
          if (levels==1)
             MessageBox.Show(actual_sites.ToString());

          return csFiles;
       }                
    }
```

The exception is thrown after a few sites have been sent to the `getLinks` function.

The exception is in the getLinks function on the line:

```
foreach (HtmlNode link in document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]"))
```

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

I tried to use there IF to check if its null then I did `return mainLinks;` which is a list.

But if I'm doing it I'm not getting all the links from the website.

Now I'm using urls in the constructor if I'm using url (`www.google.co.il`) I'm getting the same exception after few seconds.

I can't figure out why this exception is throw up. Is there any reason for this exception ?

> System.NullReferenceException was unhandled
>   Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>   Source=GatherLinks
>   StackTrace:
>   at GatherLinks.Form1.getLinks(HtmlDocument document) in D:\C-Sharp\GatherLinks\GatherLinks\GatherLinks\Form1.cs:line 55
>   at GatherLinks.Form1.webCrawler(String url, Int32 levels) in D:\C-Sharp\GatherLinks\GatherLinks\GatherLinks\Form1.cs:line 76
>   at GatherLinks.Form1.webCrawler(String url, Int32 levels) in D:\C-Sharp\GatherLinks\GatherLinks\GatherLinks\Form1.cs:line 104
>   at GatherLinks.Form1..ctor() in D:\C-Sharp\GatherLinks\GatherLinks\GatherLinks\Form1.cs:line 29
>   at GatherLinks.Program.Main() in D:\C-Sharp\GatherLinks\GatherLinks\GatherLinks\Program.cs:line 18
>   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
>   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
>   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
>   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

Comment: It'd help if you could highlight which line in `getLinks` is line 55.

Comment: You need to figure out why the reason your object reference is null and make sure before you do anything with said object you verify its not `null`.  You have a great deal more work ahead of you before we can help you.

Comment: Maybe you found a page that doesn't have any links?

Comment: Side note: If you really scrape the url/urls in your code I'm quite sure you're violating their terms of use.

Comment: Filburt i didnt know that. I did it only for my own test. Thanks for the information i will use my own sites or public ones.

Comment: What does the SelectNodes documentation say btw? Why return null and force client code to check for null when they could just return an empty list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem appears to be that you're testing for null but then doing nothing about it - here

```
            if (document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]") == null)
            {
            }
```

I suspect you want to handle the null case but haven't written the code to do it. You probably want something like:

```
    private List<string> getLinks(HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument document)
        {
           List<string> mainLinks = new List<string>();
           if (document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]") != null)
            {

                foreach (HtmlNode link in document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]"))
                {
                    var href = link.Attributes["href"].Value;
                    mainLinks.Add(href);
                }
            }
            return mainLinks;
        }
```

you'd probably want to tidy up to something more like:

```
   private List<string> getLinks(HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument document)
        {
           List<string> mainLinks = new List<string>();
           var linkNodes = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]");
           if (linkNodes != null)
            {
                foreach (HtmlNode link in linkNodes)
                {
                    var href = link.Attributes["href"].Value;
                    mainLinks.Add(href);
                }
            }
            return mainLinks;
        }
```

Comment: joocer i tried your code i dont understand why when im using this string string urls = @"http://www.bing.com/images/search?q=cat&go=&form=QB&qs=n"; im getting only 7 links. while if im browsing to the site i see then much more links and also many many photos there and each photo have its own link. So why only 7 links ? Strange.

Comment: Without reading through the source of the page in detail I'm just speculating but I reckon the seven links are the seven across the top of the page (Web Images Videos Shopping News Maps More) and that the rest of the page is created dynamically by JavaScript or within the iFrame called historyFrame which appears to be the search results.